# In Java, Is it possible to create an object without a class and a constructor?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, new-operator

there!

I'm new on Java and I recently stumbled upon constructors concept. I think that I understood the concept, but the book that I'm reading introduced the concept of **objects in arrays** and I got lost.

In the examples, the book simply creates an object using the constructor `new`. But the problem is that the book uses it with an **object reference variable** that refers to an object in a nonexistent class.

Let me write it in code.

```
Dog [] pets;

pets = new Dog[];
```

I understand that an object called `Dog` that contains arrays `[]` was created.

When, in my current understanding it should be like this:

```
//We have a class named Dog

public class Dog{

//And We have a basic default constructor here
    public Dog(){
    }

}

//We have another class

public Class2{

//In this class we create a "reference variable" 
//to create an object from the above class named Dog.


Dog[] pets;
pets= new Dog[];

}
```

So, I don't know if the book simply obviated the class named `Dog` or if it's possible to create an object `Dog[]` on demand, without having a class/constructor to call.

I'd appreciate if somebody could clarify this concepts to me.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: An object called dog that contains arrays was not created, an array object that contains Dogs was created.

Comment: Can you give some details on your goal?

Comment: @Ashish Sharma My main question is that if it's possible to create an object, an array object in this example, can be created WITHOUT having a class and constructor to take a as a reference.

Comment: Because the basic definition of a constructor is  "A Java constructor is a special method that is called when an object is INSTATIATED" and therefore, if a constructor instatiates, I guess that there MUST be a class to actually Instatiate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration `Dog[] pets;` requires there to be a class or interface named `Dog`. It declares the variable `pets` with type `Dog[]`, meaning that `pets` will always hold either `null` or a reference to an array of type `Dog[]` (or perhaps a subtype such as `Chihuahua[]`). Your book is apparently assuming that `Dog` is defined elsewhere, and letting you fill in the blanks. (This is very normal: books don't usually present whole programs for every example, because they don't want to distract from the specific thing they're showing you.)

The assignment `pets = new Dog[]` isn't valid: you can't create an array without saying how many elements it has, either with a number (`new Dog[3]`) or by explicitly listing elements (`new Dog[] { null, null, null }`).

The assignment `pets = new Dog[3]` requires there to be a class or interface named `Dog`, but it does *not* call any of `Dog`'s constructors (because it doesn't create a `Dog`, only a `Dog[]`), so it doesn't care whether `Dog` has a no-arg constructor, whether `Dog` is a concrete class, whether any of `Dog`'s constructors are accessible, or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks my friend, I think I get it but I'd like to get more of your help in solidifying the concept. Just to clarify, `Dog[]` isn't an object, but it's an array **capable of creating objects**? I mean, the array `pets Dog[3]` will be capable of creating four **instances**, or four **objects**, of the class named `Dog`, and the three objects will be associated or referenced with the variable `pets`. Is that right?

Comment: @esus4: An array actually *is* an object, but it's a special sort of object. And it can't *create* objects, but it can *hold* references to objects. For example, if `pets` is a `Dog[]`, then `pets[3]` can be a `Dog`.

Comment: Oh, I see! And if understood my book correctly, the references to objects are the things that **create** the objects (with the `new`) and then reference them. Is that right?

Comment: @esus4: References don't create objects, they just point to them. So, like, in the same way that the expression  `3 + 4 + 5` does some additions and then *evaluates* to the integer 12, the expression `new Object()` creates an object and evaluates to a reference to that object. The reference doesn't exist, at least from the programmer's standpoint, until the object has been created.

Answer (score 0):

An array isn't a class in Java, even though instantiating it uses the `new` keyword, and there is no constructor. Leaving that aside, though, let's clarify the syntax a little bit because there's some confusion over what your code actually means.

Imagine an array as a series of boxes strung together. Each box, or `element`, could possibly contain an instance of *something*. You need to tell the array what type all of its boxes are allowed to contain, and you do so by putting the name of that type prior to the square brackets. In this case, the author used a fictional `Dog` type (i.e. `Dog[]`), but it could just as well be `Integer`, `String`, or any other type. Your code creates an instance of an array that is capable of containing instances of `Dog` or its descendant types.